# ¿Cómo funciona GridSearchCV con respecto a los parámetros en python?

Tags: python, parametros, machine-learning, model

estaba practicando y me he encontrado con esta librería llamada GridSearchCV que según leí es para encontrar mejores parámetros de un modelo, pero lo que no he entendido es como seleccionar estos parámetros iniciales para GridSearchCV, pues la guía donde aprendía solamente crea esta variable diccionario **param** y añade (para mi) valores al azar, ya que antes de ello solo entrenamos el modelo y evaluamos con la matriz de confusión y otras métricas de puntuación. Mis dudas estarían si estos valores depende del modelo, quizás los extrajo de otro lado o simplemente son arbitrarios y si lo son... ¿existe alguna recomendación o alguna guía para seleccionarlos?. Aquí dejo al culpable de mi desesperación.

```
#Entrenamos
svc = SVC()
svc.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred_svc = svc.predict(X_test)

#Evaluamos
print(sklearn.metrics.classification_report(y_test, pred_svc))

print(sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, pred_svc))

#Encontrar los mejores parámetros para nuestro modelo SVC
param = {
    'C': [0.1,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4],
    'kernel':['linear', 'rbf'],
    'gamma' :[0.1,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4]
}
grid_svc = GridSearchCV(svc, param_grid=param, scoring='accuracy', cv=10)
```

Observando en esta pagina [https://www.analyticslane.com/2019/02/18/seleccionar-automaticamente-los-modelos-en-python-con-gridsearchcv/#:~:text=Utilizaci%C3%B3n%20b%C3%A1sica%20de%20GridSearchCV,los%20par%C3%A1metros%20es%20el%20segundo](https://www.analyticslane.com/2019/02/18/seleccionar-automaticamente-los-modelos-en-python-con-gridsearchcv/#:%7E:text=Utilizaci%C3%B3n%20b%C3%A1sica%20de%20GridSearchCV,los%20par%C3%A1metros%20es%20el%20segundo)

Sucede lo mismo

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

dataset = load_diabetes()

X = dataset.data
y = dataset.target

model = Ridge()
params = {'alpha': [1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001]}

grid = GridSearchCV(model, params, cv=10, iid=False)
grid.fit(X, y)

grid.best_estimator_.get_params()
```

¿Por qué esos valores?. Cualquier ayuda me sirve, espero haberme explicado bien.

De antemano Muchas gracias.

Comment: Yo creo que en el artículo te lo explica bien: "En el ejemplo se utiliza un modelo Ridge en el que se prueban diferentes valores de alpha que se evalúan con GridSearchCV. Una vez entrenado el modelo se puede consultar con qué valor de alpha se obtienen los mejores rendimientos. En este caso el valor es de 0,1.". O sea, se da una lista de valores iniciales a los parámetros y se escoje el que dé mejores resultados.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, me costo entenderlo pero logre captar el uso de este y los valores que se le pueden otorgar. Saludos @ChemaCortes